# Make predictor/variable less important in Neural Network

Tags: neural-networks, ordinal-data

I have a question regarding my Neural Network. So, my data contains multiple users who filled in Likert-scale surveys regarding their happiness level (ordinal data). I am testing multiple ways to encode ordinal data. In this case i am using One-Hot encoding for the target variable, so it is a classification & supervised learning problem

One of my predictors is the happiness level from the last filled in survey. In my opinion it's an informative predictor as it is very unlikely that if last-hapiness value is 0, next hapiness value is 5, but more likely a 1/2/3.

But what happens is that my model recognizes that last-hapiness level is most of the times the same as the next hapiness level:
last-value variable= 5, prediction = 5, 
last-value variable= 2, prediction = 2

The table below shows the predictions of the model on the test set. 
'Same level' means previous-value variable == real value
'Different level' == not the same as real value

[image: Output prediction table]

How can I make this predictor less important/informative so the model will pay more attention to my other predictors. Or how can I penalise the model in a way that he is better in predicting the 'different level'. Working with Python + Keras.

Comment: You need to give us more details on what exactly is your data and your model. What exactly does the table show? Is it classification or regression? If classification, then how do you define "close to 0"?

Comment: @Tim I updated my post. Is it more clear now?

Comment: What is your model? Is it some kind of LSTM?

Comment: @Tim, no, just a simple neural network.

Comment: Then how the model know "previous" value? You need to give us more details.

Comment: @Tim, I mentioned that I use the previous value as a predictor. So one of my predictor columns contains the previous value.

Comment: How is this question unclear? It seems pretty clear to me

Comment: @kbrose, Thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

Many ways you can do

1. Normalize the features, normalization will help reduce the "effect" of certain feature, for example in the housing prediction data, some features range between 0 and 1, but if one feature is range between 0 and 1000, that will "weight" more on that feature, so you first need to normalize the features and make them all between 0 and 1. (minmaxscaler)
2. If the problem still persists, you might need to introduce regularization, depending on your neural network, you can add L1 or L2.
3. Using dropout layers, this will randomly turn the features on and off, which will remove the effection of neural network depends on single features.